# Is there a way to disable Modern List Comments?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, modern-experience, comments

Modern List comments are now enabled in our SharePoint Online tenant. Some site owners have their own custom comments using text columns and find these modern comments confusing to their users.

Is there a way to disable these? There's no way in List Settings to disable and I tried PnP PowerShell `Set-PnPList` and could not find any property to set that would disable.

[image: Modern SharePoint List Comments]

Comment: I am having the same issue, however i was not able to find CommentsOnListItemsDisabled option in commandlet. Is there a specific version i should look for for module "Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to disable it at tenant level with the cmdlet:

```
Set-SPOTenant -CommentsOnListItemsDisabled $True
```

**Microsoft documentation**: [Set-SPOTenant](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-spotenant)

It may take some time to update the change.

---

Comment: Thanks.  Hopefully MS will update the SharePoint management shell so we can use Set-SPOSite similar to how we can disable comments on pages at the site level.

Comment: Enable/Disable list comments at SharePoint **list level** will be available very soon. Check detailed information in [this article](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/05/23/enable-disable-the-comments-for-a-sharepoint-online-microsoft-list/)

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a third part solution to disable comments for certain lists.
Here is a youtube video I have found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rk-s2DLg8QE&t=1s

Answer (score 0):

You can now disable the list comments from list settings as well.

1. Go to List settings
2. Select "Advanced settings"
3. Set "Allow comments on list items" to "No"

For detailed information, check: [How to Enable/Disable the comments for a specific SharePoint list](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/05/23/enable-disable-the-comments-for-a-sharepoint-online-microsoft-list/)

**Related Read**: [How to Enable/Disable the commenting in SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/09/how-to-enable-disable-the-commenting-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/)